# How to ungroup a Crossfilter group to carry values into new group?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

In crossfilter.js I want to group based on one key, reduce to get counts, then ungroup to carry counts into original datastructure, so that I can group on another key and get a total count.

I want to count id's per day given the following input data:

```
{day: 'Mon', id: 1}
{day: 'Fri', id: 3}
{day: 'Tue', id: 1}
{day: 'Mon', id: 2}
{day: 'Wed', id: 1}
```

The result of the id count per day is:

```
{day: 'Mon', count: 2}
{day: 'Tue', count: 1}
{day: 'Wed', count: 1}
{day: 'Thu', count: 0}
{day: 'Fri', count: 1}
```

Then I want to carry these counts back into the ungrouped data, e.g.

```
{day: 'Mon', id: 1, count: 2}
{day: 'Fri', id: 3, count: 1}
{day: 'Tue', id: 1, count: 1}
{day: 'Mon', id: 2, count: 2}
{day: 'Wed', id: 1, count: 1}
```

so that I can group on id and reduceCount on count, e.g.

```
{id:1 , totalcount: 4}
{id:2 , totalcount: 2}
{id:3 , totalcount: 1}
```

**So, is this type of ungrouping possible, or can it be achieved with a workaround?** I'm using crossfilter here for a dc.js rowChart implementation, so the implementation has to be dynamically update-able like the rest of dc.js.

EDIT 1:

I break a given sentence into overlapping substrings (phrases) of varying word length, each identified by the same sentence ID. I have a dataset of sentences that I want to summarize with a DC.js rowchart, which should show the sentences that are most representative of the frequently occurring phrases in the dataset.

So I first want to get histogram counts of the phrases to see how frequently they occur, so I have a datastructure with extracted phrases for the entire sentence dataset. I then want to take those histogram counts and sum or average the counts per sentence, where there may be multiple phrases extracted from a given sentence.

So the logic is first to see which phrases occur frequently, but instead of displaying the phrase histogram rowchart I rather display a sentence rowchart which gives full sentences that are representative of frequent phrases.

Exploring the crossfilter.dimension.group datastructure I can see there are index mappings from groups back to constituent dimension data vectors, so it must indeed be possible to carry group values into the original data vectors.

Comment: I can't really think of a way to do this. But why do you want to do this? What does it tell you to say that id 1 has a count of 4? Maybe if I understand information you are trying to convey with this approach, it'll be a little more clear how to accomplish it.

Comment: I sometimes call this a "double reduce", something crossfilter doesn't directly support. Here I don't think it makes sense: 'Mon' has multiple `id`s, so you copy the counts back to two `id`s and then count them twice: your total is 7 when there are only 5 records.

Comment: Indeed it is hard to see the point, but I tried to explain it in the above edit.

Comment: I guess the index mapping you're referring to is `groupIndex` - afaik this is not publicly accessible, and it would still take some a little because it is mapping from objects to groups, not the other way around. It's a good idea, though!

Comment: Thanks Gordon. DC.js is amazing. I'll try and find a logical workaround to achieve the objective.